# what is entity in entityframework context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to implement this action with use of EntityFramework.BulkInsert ,I checked the documentation but I'm new to EF i couldn't figure out what is entity in this context.what is entity ?

```
foreach (string tag in tags)
    {
        TagUser tagUser = new TagUser()
        {
            //Initialize TagUser
        };


        applicationUser.TagUsers.Add(tagUser);
    }

db.SaveChanges();
```

this is the sample code in its documention:

```
using (var ctx = GetContext())
{
  using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
  {
    // some stuff in dbcontext

    ctx.BulkInsert(entities);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
    transactionScope.Complete();
  }
}
```

and this is my TagUserclass:

```
public class TagUser
    {
        [Required]
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("Tag")]
        public Guid TagId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
        public string Id { get; set; }


        public virtual Tag  Tag { get; set; }


        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public bool InEnglish { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Int16 Priority { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: do you want to insert many tag users in single batch ? or many application user in single batch ?

Comment: I want to add many TagUsers  to tagUsers collection of an AppplicationUser.

Comment: show your tag user class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entities are the tag users collection and before doing the bulk insert, provide the FK id first.

```
using (var ctx = GetContext())
{
    using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var entities= new List<TagUser>();
        foreach (string tag in tags)
        {
            TagUser tagUser = new TagUser()
            {
                //Initialize TagUser
                TagId = ..., // get something like tag.Id
                Id = applicationUser.Id
            };
            entities.Add(tagUser);
        }

        ctx.BulkInsert(entities);

        ctx.SaveChanges();
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this context `entities` would be your list of entities that you're trying to insert. So instead of saying `TagUsers.Add(taguser)` every time, you might get the list of TagUsers you want to insert in a `List<TagUser> tagusers` (maybe like that, I haven't used BulkInsert personally), and say `applicationUser.BulkInsert(tagusers)`

Comment: I tried that but BulkInsert is a extention method for DbContext